# How to train a layer multiple times in a pass for variable amount of input features?

Tags: time-series, lstm, training

I'm training an LSTM on multi-feature time-series location data. How can I design a network structure that can take one primary location's features, plus an *arbitrary* number $n$ of extra "neighbor" locations' features alongside the primary location's features? (All locations have the same data features for the same dates)

I have an idea but I do not know how exactly to implement it properly, nor if it is even the correct approach.

For example, assume the dataset has columns like: `date, A, B, C, D, location_name, latitude, longitude`. The numerical features would be `A, B, C, D`. In my data they have all been normalized by series in the whole dataset (i.e. all A for all locations have a common mean and std. dev., but B's mean and std. dev. is different than A's).

- The primary LSTM would take $3$ features in this example: the primary location's `A, B, C` features.
- The secondary LSTM would take $4$ features: another location's `A, B, C, distance` features (at the same dates as the primary sequence), where `distance` is generated and represents how far this location is from the primary location. This intends to let the LSTM account for distance in the relationship while training.
- The goal is that the network predicts the latest `D` value for the primary location.

On the forward pass, this hypothetical network would:

1. feed the $3$ features of the primary location through the primary LSTM, and produce an output;
2. feed the $4$ features each of $n$ neighbor locations through the secondary LSTM, *one pass for each location*, producing $n$ total outputs from the secondary LSTM;
3. combine all $n+1$ intermediate LSTM outputs through a third layer (ex. Dense?) that will produce $1$ output: the latest `D` value for the primary location.

and this is where my idea is stuck. First, I do not know what this third layer can be. I would be looking for a layer that can transform an arbitrary number of inputs into one output, and also be able to backpropagate. I know I could perform a weighted average of all the values along the feature axis, but I can't backpropagate an average (to my knowledge). Second, I do not know if the secondary LSTM needs to take a different loss than the primary LSTM during backpropagation.

The appeal to me of having two LSTMs and one other layer is that backpropagation should be a nice constant time with respect to $n$ neighbors ($3+4n$ total features).

What should the third layer be? Should I only have one LSTM, combine the outputs with an average weighted by location distance of each output?

Or am I approaching this problem wrong? I have never worked with a network that can handle a variable number of features. I am partially aware of CNNs but I only know of them as handling non-time-dependent data.